# Lords of Midnight (8 bit version) - did anyone complete it? If so, how?

Tags: commodore-64, lords-of-midnight

I had many happy (& frustrating days) playing Lords of Midnight on the C64.  However I never came close to completing it.  The idea seemed simple, get Morkin to destroy the Ice Crown, or get Luxor's armies together to defeat Doomdark's armies.

However the further North I got with Morkin, the more likely he was to die when fighting something stupid (and getting to the point where I was surrounded and had to fight).  Meanwhile I'd be recruiting armies, and seeming quite good, but suddenly get caught out running into a seriously big enemy army and not be able to marshal my armies together to defeat them.

Did anyone out there finish this / or have any tips on how to do so? I'd consider revisiting it, but wondering if it is even possible or if it is unbeatable?

Comment: Voting to leave open. Not sure how this is any more opinion based that lots of other questions like "how do I defeat this boss", which seem to be on-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My tips would be:

- Send Luxor south and recruit as many lords as you can and reinforce the Citadel of Xajorkith with a dozen lords. It has to be protected to win the game!
- Send Rorthron east as a "diplomat", recruiting!
- Send Morkin north, with an escort; you'll recruit Lord Shadows and Lord Blood early on, so use them!
- I use several strategic points around the map, Citadels of Gloom, Dreams and Ithrorn for protection, use these for the final assault or to snatch the ice crown!
- After about 50-70 days, you'll wear the enemy down and be able to launch an offensive!

Comment: haven't played and beat it yet.  Thanks for the tips.  I think I used to send most people East other than Morkin which meant my armies tended to get picked off.

Answer (score 2):

Thought I'd start answering my own question as no replies yet.

I've found the following site after lots of googling: http://www.icemark.com/tower/index.html which seems to have some good tips.  I found this from the Yahoo group, http://games.groups.yahoo.com/group/midnight which contains plenty of people who have finished the game.  So it's definitely beatable.  I'll have a read of the icemark site and see if the tips are good.  If they are I may have to have another go at this game.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 2):

There's a complete gameplay video at [archive.org](http://www.archive.org/details/C64Videoarchive175-LordsOfMidnight), it comes from [C64 Longplays](http://www.c64-longplays.de/videos.php)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The question is literally "did anyone complete it". I think this would answer the question, even if the link were dead, by showing that someone did.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: Yes, I was then able to beat Doomdark playing on the ZX Spectrum. Beating his armies and conquering the citadel of Ushgarak is really hard work, though.

It's a lot easier to destroy the Ice Crown. Send Morkin and Rothron to the northwest and recruit Farflame the Dragonlord. Farflame is a mighty one-dragon-army and can protect Morkin from most of the "stupid" enemies like wolves and even some smaller enemy armies. Lothoril and Gloom can serve as some stepping points on the way to the Tower of Doom. (Don't forget to stop at Weirdhenge, where he can get an additional day to play.) If Farflame is still alive, he can destroy the Ice Crown. If not, head back southwest to Lake Mirrow.

Here is a [map of Midnight](http://www.icemark.com/tower/maps/htmlmap/map.htm) that should help you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The game is completable in 10 days, using Farflame to destroy the Ice-Crown. If you head through the Downs of Mirrow, there is a long run of Liths which have the cup of dreams, which will allow Morkin to reach the Citadel of Gloom in just a few days, from there it's a straight run across the top of the map and through the mountains and round the back of the Tower of Doom. Use Farflame and Lord of Shadows to knock out any wolves etc, but don't attack any large armies with Farflame unless you have to. Shadows will move more slowly, but he has a head start on Morkin anyway, if he gets attacked, just move on until you reach Gloom as at that point there is only 1 army that might stop Morkin in that area.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The first time by sneaking Morkin all the way north along the east side of the mark while the armies battled it out in the plains and the mountains. At other times by defending Shimeril until I gathered enough armies to take back the Plains of Blood, and then pushing north. Interestingly, by absolutely crushing each single keep, you may lose so few men that  you can actually make your army grow.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I remember I managed to recruit all Lords, not losing a single soldier, freeing every keep and citadel. It is important to not lose at least a citadel or keep with fey warriors AND riders or you can't pass soldiers between fey armies and defend keep of utarg because it is the only targ keep. I defended Dreams and Dregrim. You can do it concentrating 2 big armies 1 in Utarg keep and one at xajorkith. You need a small army to defend Dreams it is usually ignored. You shall use farflame to slow down enemy armies and battle enemies always with superior numbers so you lose no soldiers at all. I instead gathered more soldiers than the beginning because you get some extra soldiers when you conquer enemy keeps and soldiers. I remember one of the most difficult task was to get out Korinel the fey from that hell without engaging battle.